# How to open & close sidenav on clicking a toggle button using material component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am new to Angular 2.  How to open a sidenav using mat component in Angular2.
I am using this site but cannot resolve the issue. I have two different components Header, Sidebar. The toggle button is in Header component and sidenav is different component. I have tried using Event Emitter as well as services but cannot resolve the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGVOI.png)

https://material.angular.io/components/categories`

Comment: Can you provide an example on stackblitz?

Comment: @GregorDoroschenko I want to use services to access one component to another via click on toggle button i am trying to open a sidebar. As beforo i have done this in other project 
import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem .. i came up with the following sollution.

So i have a separate Navbar(`nav-bar.component.ts`)Component and a separate SideBar(`sidebar.component.ts`).

You were on the right path except i think the `@HostBinding('class.open')` is not a valid class for side nav. I came up with the below solution.

### sidenav.component.ts

```
export class SideNavComponent implements OnDestroy{
isOpen: boolean;
    ngOnInit(){

        this._sideNavService.change.subscribe(isOpen =>{
            console.log(isOpen)
            this.isOpen = isOpen;
        })
    }
}
```

Below is the HTML for my side nav. **NOTE : We can use property binding and bind to the "opened" property of the sidenav. I am using the variable isOpen to do that.**

### sidenav.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav [(opened)]="isOpen" [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'" [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
        <div>Some Text<div>

    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Another thing to note is that I have placed a text in a div because apparently this implicitly creates a `<mat-sidenav-content>` tab without which the side nav wont be visible**
I wrote a basic directive for the Navbar.

### nav-bar.directive.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener, Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SideNavService } from "../_services/sideNav.service"; 

@Directive({ selector: '[sidebarButton]' })
export class HostDirective {
    constructor(private sideNavService:SideNavService){}

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        console.log("Called")
        this.sideNavService.toggle();
    }

}
```

And a sideNav service for the two components to communicate.

### sideNav.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class SideNavService{
    isOpen = false;

    @Output() change: EventEmitter <boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    toggle(){
        console.log("event fired")
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        this.change.emit(this.isOpen);
    }
}
```

**The above solution just fixes what the question mentions but is not an elegant solution**